# ListConnectionStrings cosmosDB permission

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I'm using ListConnectionStrings in the ARM template to retrieve the connection strings from cosmosDB

```
{listConnectionStrings(resourceId(cosmosDBSubscription, cosmosDBResourceGroup,'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', cosmosdbAccount), '2022-08-15').connectionStrings[2].connectionString}
```

The index 2 returns primary read only connection string. I'm trying to provide access to cosmosDB for applications in a different subscription in an automated way. I have two questions on this

1. what permission is required for calling 'listConnectionStrings' on cosmosDB
2. Is it possible to restrict access to only read only keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RBAC action that provides permission for calling list connection strings is

```
Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/listConnectionStrings/*
```

It is possible to restrict access to read only keys. You do however need to add some additional RBAC actions for that to be useful. The [Cosmos DB Account Reader Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cosmos-db-account-reader-role) may do what you need.

You can find more [Azure role-based access control in Azure Cosmos DB information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to restrict access to readonly connection string. The listConnectionStrings/* gives access to all connection strings, right ?

Comment: Yes, "actions" gives permission, "notActions" removes them when creating a custom role.